# AJAX SEO (re: faceted search w/ URL hashed state )

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, hash, seo

I'm reusing an AJAX faceted search framework I wrote for a previous website, which is all AJAX and stores the page state (for browser back button support) in the URL's hash. You can see it in action here w/ something like this:

[http://www.carnegiefabrics.com/productsearch.aspx#v={-f-.{-Usage-.[653]*-Color-.[902]}*-p-.1_-s-.--}](http://www.carnegiefabrics.com/productsearch.aspx#v=%7B-f-.%7B-Usage-.%5B653%5D_-Color-.%5B902%5D%7D_-p-.1_-s-.--%7D)

In this new project I want the contents to be able to be crawled by search engines, so I need the results to render w/o JavaScript -- that is, by the server.

NOTE: I don't want to use Google's hash solution (using the '!') because it's too magical and it's Google-only.

I'm thinking of having the initial page load (which will have all facets set to "all") render ALL of the results directly from the server. SE will then be able to crawl them. Then, I'll strip the extra results (anything above what should be on page 1) via JavaScript. This will correct the UI for the user, and everything will be AJAX from here.

It's a little awkward, but it's the best solution I have currently. What are people's thoughts/suggestions on this approach?

Answer (score 1):

> In this new project I want the contents to be able to be crawled by search engines, so I need the results to render w/o JavaScript -- that is, by the server.

It is impossible to do it without JavaScript. The hash part of the url is not sent to the server. So the server is not able to read it. That is why this model stinks.

> What are people's thoughts/suggestions on this approach?

In browsers that support HTML5, you should use The new [History methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to control the browser state which allows you to generate a hashless url!

Comment: +1 I agree. If not a [hashbang](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content) or similar solution, then pushState is a good solution.

Comment: It has to support non-HTML5 browsers, so those solutions won't work. My plan was to have it render ALL of the results. The server wouldn't have to know the hash because it would essentially be showing "all".